# IronRuby bug or normal?

Tags: forms, ironruby

I installed IronRuby on my computer and wanted to try simple things like creating a window:

```
require "System.Windows.Forms"
include System::Windows::Forms
form = Form.new
form.Title = "Hello IronRuby" # This doesn't work. ("Undefined method Title= for System.Windows.Forms.Form")
form.Show
```

This is not the only strange thing. When I `Show` a Windows Form, (without trying to set the title) the Form instantly crashes. **Did I make something wrong or is this a bug or something different?**

[image: Screenshot of my problem]

**EDIT:** The problem with `form.Title` was solved by *Paul Lambert*. By I'm still wondering, if it is normal, that the Forms crash instantly, when I call `form.show`?

Comment: Yes, that's expected -- see edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use form.Text instead of form.Title.  See [this start-up guide](http://www.ironshay.com/post/Starting-Using-IronRuby-in-25-Minutes.aspx)

Edit: I don't think the script crashes, but merely exits instantly, since the form is non-modal and no controls or handlers are defined.  Replace `form.Show` with `form.ShowDialog` for the window to persist until the user closes it.

Comment: Thanks. My thoughts were apparently in WPF :D